# Change class according to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this array:

```
var size = [small, medium, large];
```

and this element:

```
<div class="wp-one wp-two wp-small"></div>
```

How do I change the size class looping through the `size` array in JQuery on pressing a `button`? For example if the element has `wp-small`, change to `wp-medium` and so forth looping through the array.

```css
.wp-small {
  color: #f00;
}
.wp-medium {
  color: #0f0;
}
.wp-large {
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="wp-one wp-two wp-small">fdgbfbfnghn</div>

<button>CHANGE CLASS</button>
```

Comment: Please clarify; Change what to what based on what?

Comment: What should we change it to?

Comment: So if its medium, you want large and if its large, you want small?

Comment: Doesn't make any sense. What is being change and based on what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var size = ['small', 'medium', 'large'];
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var id= document.getElementById("sentence");
var i = 0;
button.onclick = function(){
    sentence.classList.remove("wp-"+size[i]);
    (i == size.length - 1) ? i = 0 : i++;
    sentence.classList.add("wp-"+size[i]);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1mugmrh/8/)

It could probably be tidied up but I'm no JS Wizard.

Basically, the first 4 lines are just me putting stuff into variables. Simple stuff.

I then make a function that on the click of `button`, it removes the class from the element that is current in the `size array`. It then checks to see what number the `i` is at (starting at 0) and if it's larger than the length of `size`, it resets back to the beginning, if not, it goes to the next array element.

It can be done in jQuery too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var size = ['small', 'medium', 'large'],
        button = $("#button"),
        sentence= $("#sentence"),
        i = 0;

    button.click(function(){
        sentence.removeClass("wp-"+size[i]);
        (i == size.length - 1) ? i = 0 : i++;
        sentence.addClass("wp-"+size[i]);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1mugmrh/9/)

But will be faster and just as simple in pure JavaScript

Comment: The `wp-one` and `wp-two`classes are variable, can be other different classes, so I can't just use them as selectors.

Comment: Thanks this worked, marked the wrong answer, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add this jQuery code:

```
 $(function(){
    currSize = 0;
    maxSize = (size.length - 1);
    $('button').on('click', function(){
       $('.wp-one').removeClass('wp-'+size[currSize]);
       if (currSize < maxSize){
          currSize++;
       }
       else{
          currSize = 0;
       }
       $('.wp-one').addClass('wp-'+size[currSize]);
    }); 
 });
```

Comment: I love how this is accepted even tho it's using jQuery. Makes no sense. edit : apparently OP suddendly added jQuery in the tags. Pretty sure it wasn't there first.

Comment: It isn't even that clever either (the code). With a `maxSize` instead of getting the array length. The code in question doesn't even have a bit to add the class either! @Enjoyted

Comment: You're right about the length but the question isn't clear neither about what will change in the future or whatelse

Comment: Also you're not adding a class after you've changed the array index.

Comment: I think it removed the class small and the default behavior of "no small" class was the same as the medium class

Comment: It should be `"wp-"+size[currSize]` and also `addClass` doesn't use `.` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

is that what you need ?

```
var state = 0;

var size = ['small', 'medium', 'large'];

btn = document.getElementById('changeSize');
div = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    state = state == size.length - 1 ? 0 : state + 1;
    btn.className = 'wp-' + size[state]; 
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70f7v86L/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to alter through the availyble sizes, so that a wp-small element will be a wp-medium element and so on? And large ones will be small again?

If so try this:

```
buttonclickHandler = function(e) {
  for(i=size.length;i>0;i--) {
    var nextIndex = i % size.length;
    $(".wp-" + size[i-1]).switchClass(".wp-" + size[i-1],".wp-" + size[nextIndex]);
  }
}
```

Although in this code you'd have the problem that large elements would be first changed to small elements and later on to medium elements (within one single click). So you'd have to remember those initially large ones and exclude them from the small-to-medium-changes. 
Due to simplicity I did not include that in the code above.